# Array slicing: access first two elements in reverse order running for loop

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

Suppose I have 1D array of length 10:

```
A = np.arange(10)
```

I would like to access 2 elements at a time and reverse them. After that A would look like this:

```
np.array([1,0,3,2,5,4,7,6,9,8])
```

I do this in for loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    A[2*i:2*i+2] = A[2*i+1:2*i-1:-1]
```

This solution works for i!=0. Is it possible to get desired output for ALL elements, without special case for i?

*I used 1D just as an example. My actual array is 2D, with y and x coordinates as rows. cv2.fitEllipse and cv.drawContours require array where x and y are columns ((2,n)->(n,1,2)). I have to change the shape of my array and reverse the order (and I would like to do this in 1 operation).

Comment: You change the shape with `.reshape(...)`, and reverse the order with `[...::-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> arr.reshape(arr.size/2, 2)[:,::-1].flatten()
array([1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8])
```

For in-place modification:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> arr[::2], arr[1::2] = arr[1::2], arr[::2].copy()
>>> arr
array([1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8])
```

Calling `.copy()` is required because by the time Python will reach `arr[1::2]` on LHS the items at `arr[::2]` are already modified.

Comment: It's a little simpler with: `arr.reshape(-1, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

For your actual OpenCV use case, the following works in a single shot:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> a[::-1, None,:].T
array([[[5, 0]],

       [[6, 1]],

       [[7, 2]],

       [[8, 3]],

       [[9, 4]]])
>>> a[::-1, None,:].T.shape
(5, 1, 2)
```

The indexing reverses the order of the columns and adds the extra dimension. And the default behavior of transpose is to reverse the order of the dimensions, which completes what you were after